# Left join is repeating the first row of left table

Tags: php, sql, database

I have two tables (post_image, sermon) that I am performing LEFT JOIN on, but the left table (post_image) is just repeat the first row and not moving downwards.
Ex:
**Post_image table**
hello.png
coming.png

**sermon table**
love
His second coming

**Result table**

1. hello.png == love
2. (still) hello.png == His second coming

**Expected table result**

1. hello.png == love
2. coming.png == His second coming

below is my code. thanks

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT post_image.image_path, sermon.user_id, sermon.preacher, sermon.title, sermon.message from post_image
                        LEFT JOIN sermon ON
                        sermon.user_id = post_image.user_id GROUP BY
                        
                        sermon.id, sermon.preacher 
                        ");
```

[**edited**]
Screenshot of my the[image: Left Join]. So the highlighted areas are repeating i couldn't capture everything. but that is the row that is repeating.

Comment: This is happening because there is no join key as such , you can create a new column called rn using window function row_number  and post that join on both the table

Comment: @dsk I don't understand

Comment: You mention several columns in your query that you don't show in your sample data. To name a few `user_id`, `sermon.id`, `sermon.preacher`. Please add them to the sample data. The questions is unclear without all the data.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have added screenshot

Comment: Add sample data from both table at least for columns you are using in the script.

Comment: What are the primary keys and foreign keys in your tables?

Comment: sermon.user_id, POST_IMAGE.USER_ID == FK while sermon.id==PK